# How to check if multiple Mesh Renderers are active at once in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, components, renderer

I've been banging my head against my desk for a few nights on this script and can't quite figure it out, I was hoping to find some help from the knowledgeable folks here!

The objective for my script is that when the player interacts with three objects that have inactive mesh renderers (in this case, "Sword" "Shield" and "Crown"), their mesh renderers will be turned on (this is handled in a separate, working script), and then ONLY when all three object's mesh renderers are active, objToTurnOn will then become active, otherwise I want objToTurnOn to stay inactive.

However, when I run my game, objToTurnOn is immediately set to active, even though the Sword, Shield, and Crown game objects all have inactive mesh renderers.

I have tried so many different ways of writing this, and am kind of at a dead end on my current knowledge with Unity and C#.  I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objToTurnOn;

    public GameObject Sword;
    public GameObject Shield;
    public GameObject Crown;
    

    void Start()
    {
    
    }

   void Update()
    {

        if (Sword.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled == true && Shield.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled == true && Crown.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled == true);

        {
            objToTurnOn.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the renderers are disabled? Or is it rather the GameObjects that are inactive?